# How can I deal with the mismatch between the vocabularies of questions and answers in a closed domain QA system?

Tags: machine-learning, natural-language, information-retrieval

I am building a question answering system that given a legal document attempts to answer questions related to the document. For example a tenancy agreement is given to the system and the user asks questions about the agreement.

I am splitting the legal document into small segments and try to find the most similar segment to each question. I am using a combination of `tf-idf` and word-embeddings based similarity measures.

The problem I have at the moment is the questions are asked by non-legal experts and almost entirely are in everyday language, therefore there is a huge mismatch between terms used in the questions and the answers (segments).
Because I do not have access to a huge collection of legal documents, I am using the prebuilt [GloVe vectors](https://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/glove/). Even if I manage to estimate the word embeddings based on relevant legal documents the mismatch problem would still remain.

How can I deal with this problem? Is there a method to augment the word embeddings to fit a certain domain, like [this](https://github.com/mfaruqui/retrofitting/)?

Comment: I think this is going to be really hard to do unless you have a lot of data.